# Convert an image to a B&W or sepia or antique brown tones in Magento

Tags: magento, plugins, colors, themes

I want to convert image in B/W and Sepia Color online in my Magento Store ..

I tried to use many color swatch extension and also tried to do it manually.

I don't want to upload different color images of my products. I just want to do it online .. User can able to change color of products online.

Please let me know guys if there is any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try a jquery plugin such as http://rendro.github.io/vintageJS/

Comment: @Rahul Dambare How do you want to convert the image during upload it self or at some other event?